# Taking differences of categorical variable in respond to a continuous variable in r

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation, data-wrangling

Given the sample data:

```
treatment <- c('treatement', 'control','treatement', 'control','treatement', 'control')
PDE.kg.ha <- c(1800, 1750, 950, 750,2100, 2000)

df <- data.frame(treatment, PDE.kg.ha)
```

I want to create a new variable in the data frame called **"yieldDiff"**: the difference in yield of millet per hectare for each pair of plots, with the yield for the control plot subtracted from the yield for the treated plot.

What this means is that, in the treatment variable in the dataset, it has two levels called *"traitement"* and *"controle"*. I want to take the difference corresponding yield in hectare (PDE.kg.ha) variable. Thus *controle yield in hectare* minus *traitement yield in hectare*. How do I write an R code to compute this?

Example: 1750 - 1800, 750 - 950, 2000 - 2100

Thus: yieldDiff <- c(-50, -200, -100)

Also, how do I write an R code to get the mean yield of the pairs of plots in order to create a new variable as **yieldMean**

**NB:** The pair of plots is the treatment column; thus 'treatement' and 'controle'

```
#Creating 3 new variables
df['yieldDiff'] <- #code I need help from the information I have given
df['yieldMean'] <- #code I need help from the information I have given
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this `dplyr`/`tidy` approach which first enumerates the treatment/control pairs then restructures the data to wide format before performing the calculations:

```
df %>%
  mutate(instance = rep(1:(nrow(df)/2), each = 2)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = PDE.kg.ha) %>%
  mutate(yieldDiff = control - treatement,
         yieldMean = (control + treatement) / 2)
```

Output:

```
#   instance treatement control yieldDiff yieldMean
#      <int>      <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1        1       1800    1750       -50      1775
# 2        2        950     750      -200       850
# 3        3       2100    2000      -100      2050
```

Comment: I am getting NA's when I run it in the whole dataset.

Comment: Do you have `NA`s in you dataset?

Comment: Yes but I have been able to resolved it by removing the NA's.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this method and it works fine.

```
yieldDiff <- PDE.kg.ha[fuma5_df$treatment=="traitement"]- PDE.kg.ha[fuma5_df$treatment=="controle"] 
yieldMean <- (PDE.kg.ha[fuma5_df$treatment=="traitement"] + PDE.kg.ha[fuma5_df$treatment=="controle"])/2

fina_df <- subset(df, subset=(treatment=="treatement"))
fina_df$yieldDiff <- yieldDiff
fina_df$yieldMean <- yieldMean
```

OUTPUT:

```
treatment PDE.kg.ha yieldDiff yieldMean
1 treatement      1800        50      1775
3 treatement       950       200       850
5 treatement      2100       100      2050
```